# How can I get 'page links' from 'every page'?

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, web-crawler, href

I want to get 'every page links' from 'every page' by python3.

Where the place 'every page' is located in BaseUrl in my code. And, the every page links located in body in my code.

Where,

```
BaseUrl = 'https://www.jobplanet.co.kr/companies?sort_by=review_compensation_cache&industry_id=700&page='

select body = #listCompanies > div > div.section_group > section:nth-child(1) > div > div > dl.content_col2_3.cominfo > dt > a'
```

plz, check my code. I want to collect every links from every page so that make a Link list as linkUrl. Is there Anything wrong?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import os
import re
import requests
import json

# jobplanet
BaseUrl = 'https://www.jobplanet.co.kr/companies?sort_by=review_compensation_cache&industry_id=700&page='


for i in range(1, 5, 1):
        url = BaseUrl + str(i)
        r = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')
        body = soup.select('#listCompanies > div > div.section_group > section:nth-child(1) > div > div > dl.content_col2_3.cominfo > dt > a')
        #print(body)

        linkUrl = []
        for item in body:
            link = item.get('href')
            linkUrl.append(link)
print(linkUrl)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS selector you have selected it returns only one record.I have provide simpler css selector to returns all 10 records per page.

You need define list outside the loop.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

linkUrl = []
BaseUrl = 'https://www.jobplanet.co.kr/companies?sort_by=review_compensation_cache&industry_id=700&page={}'
for i in range(1, 6):
    url = BaseUrl.format(i)
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')
    links=soup.select(".us_titb_l3 >a")
    for item in links:
        link = item.get('href')
        linkUrl.append(link)

print(linkUrl)
```

Answer (score 1):

your Css selector was wrong also added the pagination

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import os
import re
import requests
import json
from urllib import parse

# jobplanet
BaseUrl = 'https://www.jobplanet.co.kr/companies?sort_by=review_compensation_cache&industry_id=700&page={}'
source  =  requests.get(BaseUrl.format(1))
soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text,'lxml')
last_page_index = soup.select('a[class="btn_pglast"]') # getting the last page index 
last_page_index = int(last_page_index[0].get('href').split('page=')[1]) if last_page_index else 1
for i in range(1, last_page_index):
    print('## Getting Page {} out of {}'.format(i,last_page_index))
    if i > 1: # to avoid getting the same page again
        url = BaseUrl.format(i)
        r = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')
    body = soup.select('dt[class="us_titb_l3"] a')
    linkUrl = []
    for item in body:
        link = item.get('href')
        link = parse.urljoin(BaseUrl, link)
        linkUrl.append(link)
print(linkUrl)
```